# Trying to get to the command prompt through recovery disk

Tags: windows, windows-vista, command-line, troubleshooting, windows-registry

I'm trying to reach the command prompt through a vista recovery disk I have, and it boots from the disk and gets to the point where it asks which installation I want to repair and then says the disk is not compatible with my version of windows. I have a dual boot setup with Vista and server 2008 R2.

Is there another was to run check disk? I can't boot in safemode or normally, I suspect a driver (atipcie) is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SHIFT+F10` to bring up the command line when booting from a windows installation medium, though if available, I would recommend using the Windows Server 2008 R2 installer instead, as Windows Vista might not be capable of handling a dual boot with a newer OS.

Since neither operating system appears to be functioning, try repairing your MBR with the bootsect.exe command, if check disk fails to solve the problem. This will kill your dual boot setup, but hopefully will at least get you started with a functional Vista.